# 2.8 Normal map and Texture issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, normals

Don't know if it's just because 2.8 is still in the process of making, but here's my problem. I have this man mesh (from cgtrader) that came with a normal map and this texture that matches it to put color in the right place. The problem: It comes out black. I've looked everywhere and this seems to be the right node setup, but help is appreciated. Thanks!

[image: The Nodes:]

BTW here's the link to the mesh I downloaded if you wanna try: https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/character/man/3d-character-96a5df4b-49ab-411b-9e1d-fd6e47537e41

Comment: If it is a real normal map you don't need the normal map node.

Comment: okay. lemme try

Comment: Nope still black

Comment: Your normal map node is currently set to "blender object space". Are you sure that is the correct space? "Tangent" is much more common, especially for a character model that may be rigged.

Comment: @JtheNinja switched back to tangent. still black. Not rigged btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the normal map node from 'Blender Object Space' to 'Tangent Space' and select the 'UV map'in the dropdown that appears, that should work.

[image]

If it still appears black, then something else must be wrong. No lights, that sort of thing. I've uploaded my file (which is working for me), so you can compare: [character.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51796)

Comment: Thanks. I have that box, but when I click on it, there's no map selection...How'd you do that part?

Comment: In other words, which uv map option did you use?

Comment: That map was already there for me, i.e. the model is already unwrapped. Did you import the OBJ file? That's the one I used.

Comment: Huh. I definitely will check that out and see if it’s works. Thank you!